# contract.set is not a function

Tags: solidity, truffle, web3-react

I am learning Ethereum development, I downloaded the react truffle suit and then tried to change some code to insert a string into the blockchain and then echo it.
But I have an error which says: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): contract.set is not a function

**App.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SimpleStorageContract from "./contracts/SimpleStorage.json";
import getWeb3 from "./getWeb3";

import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = { storageValue: "", web3: null, accounts: null, contract: null, newValue: "" };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      // Get network provider and web3 instance.
      const web3 = await getWeb3();

      // Use web3 to get the user's accounts.
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

      // Get the contract instance.
      const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
      const deployedNetwork = SimpleStorageContract.networks[networkId];
      const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
        SimpleStorageContract.abi,
        deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
      );

      // Set web3, accounts, and contract to the state, and then proceed with an
      // example of interacting with the contract's methods.
      this.setState({ web3, accounts, contract: instance }, this.runExample);
    } catch (error) {
      // Catch any errors for any of the above operations.
      alert(
        `Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract. Check console for details.`,
      );
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({newValue: event.target.value });
  }

  async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { accounts, contract } = this.state;
    await contract.set(this.state.newValue, {from: accounts[0]});
    const response = await contract.get();
    this.setState({storageValue: response });
  }

  runExample = async () => {
    const { contract } = this.state;

    // Get the value from the contract to prove it worked.
    const response = await contract.methods.get().call();

    // Update state with the result.
    this.setState({ storageValue: response });
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.web3) {
      return <div>Loading Web3, accounts, and contract...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Sample</h1>
        <div>Text: {this.state.storageValue}</div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.newValue} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}></input>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is the contract which the set function is declared:

**SimpleStorage.sol:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    string storedData;

    constructor(string memory x) public {
      storedData = x;
    }

    function set(string memory x) public {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() public view returns (string memory) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line in your code uses syntax of the [Truffle](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts#making-a-transaction) package:

```
await contract.set(this.state.newValue, {from: accounts[0]});
```

But your code only imports [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/) (not Truffle) and seems to be using it correctly in other places.

In web3js, you need to use the `methods` property (same as you're using in `contract.methods.get()`) of the `contract` object. As well as the `send()` function (that accepts the object with the `from` property) to send a transaction instead of a call.

So it should be

```
await contract.methods.set(this.state.newValue).send({from: accounts[0]});
```

*Note: Web3js and Truffle are two separate packages, not related to each other. But both can be used to interact with smart contracts.*